# Group default.plymouth is broken

Tags: plymouth

If I try to change the plymouth theme I get this error and plymouth is displayed only in text mode:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative

```
/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth because link group default.plymouth is broken.
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth with a link.
```

How to fix this?
I am using ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 2):

This error message indicates that you have somehow replaced the /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth symlink, which is managed by the plymouth theme packages, with a real file.  Since you want to select a different theme, you can accomplish this by running:

```
sudo rm -f /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

If the contents of /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth are something you care about preserving, you can move the file aside instead of removing it.

Answer (score 0):

try to `gksu nautilus` and go to `lib/plymouth/themes` and open your default.plymouth file and make sure it has all the right filenames

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=INT2MIL-Ubuntu-10.10-Eng theme #this should right the name of the folder of your theme
Description=Ubuntu plymounth theme
ModuleName=script

[script]
ImageDir=/lib/plymouth/themes/INT2MIL-Ubuntu-10.10-Eng
ScriptFile=/lib/plymouth/themes/INT2MIL-Ubuntu-10.10-Eng/mdv.script
```

make sure it is correct and also check the directory for your current theme and see if any files are missing.

Ohh and instead of doing a `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`  you can edit the default.plymouth file and change the theme name, image directory and script directory to your new theme and the just `sudo update-initramfs -u`

And on your next boot you will see the new Plymouth splash if all went well. Good luck